# Placement Viewing with Custom Form Widget

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6, orchardcms-1.7

I detailed this problem here: [Orchard Discussions](https://orchard.codeplex.com/discussions/466873).

Basically, I am trying to customize how Custom Forms get displayed. Here is what I did in a nutshell:

1. I created an alternate in my Theme: Parts.CustomForm.Wrapper-url-myurl.cshtml - did this to style the wrapper of the form.
2. I created an alternate in my Theme: Content.Edit-MyForm.cshtml and added, among the `<div>` styling I did, this:

   ```
   ...
   @Display(Model.FirstName)
   ...
   @Display(Model.MyCheckBox)
   ...
   ```
3. I added this to the placement file in my Theme:

   ```
   <Match ContentType="MyForm">
       <Place Fields_Input_Edit-FirstName="FirstName:1"/>
       ...
       <Place Fields_Enumeration_Edit-MyCheckBox="MyCheckBox:1"/>
       ...
   </Match>
   ```

The form was set up the normal way you set up Custom Forms. I just wanted some control over how it was displayed for which normal CSS was insufficient. I almost got there, but the checkbox (enumeration field) is NOT showing up to anonymous users. HOWEVER, all other fields show up (even other enumeration fields that are radio button lists or drop down lists).

What's odd is that if I log in, then the checkbox (along with all other fields that displayed to anonymous users) shows up.

Anonymous users have "submit" permission to the custom form under Roles.

What am I missing? Or is this a bug?

Using Orchard 1.7.1.

Comment: I have exactly same issue, enumeration field doesn't display to anonymous users https://orchard.codeplex.com/workitem/20303

Comment: @Xeevis I voted that up.